# select id if more than twenty columns satisfying conditions

Tags: mysql, hibernate, criteria, restriction

Ideally i need the query in Hibernate Criteria API, but it will be very helpful even in Native-SQL. I have a table with columns id, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, ... a25. i need to retrieve id if for more than 20 columns condition "between(min, max)" will be satisfyed. thanx for any advice, point to solution or even solution itself.

Comment: How about normalizing your table structure?

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT id_field
 FROM table_name 
 WHERE IF(a1 BETWEEN min_value AND max_value, 1, 0)
     + IF(a2 BETWEEN min_value AND max_value, 1, 0)
     ...
     + IF(a25 BETWEEN min_value AND max_value, 1, 0) > 20
```